# Problemas com o .jar

Tags: java, jar

Bom dia pessoal, bom tenho um projeto Maven rodando sobre o Netbeans porém, o `.jar` gerado diz na hora da execução: *"nenhum atributo de manifesto principal em exemplo.jar"*.

Ouvi falar que poderia ser algum problema no arquivo `MANIFEST.MF`, mas não obtive sucesso em modificá-lo, também ouvi falar sobre um plugin chamado `maven-shade-plugin`, que poderia ajudar a gerar o .jar com as dependências, porém não entendi como usá-lo, então gostaria de uma ajuda de vocês pra conseguir gerar o bendito executável.

Gostaria de antemão, já agradecer a toda comunidade pelo excelente trabalho feito neste fórum.

Answer (score 1):

Faltou setar qual a classe que possui o main.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>com.mycompany.stackoverflow.teste.App</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

A classe principal é colocada na tag mainClass.
Esse trecho tem que ser adicionado no arquivo pom.xml, dentro da tag project.